# load page to the same page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im developing plugin into wordpress. I click on my plugin in admin menu and in window appears user login. Under the user login I did new register account like hyperlink (with html tag a).

```
<a class="hyper" href="file.php">Register new account</a>
```

But this link redirects to 
  **localhost/my_project/wp-admin/file.php**  but  this file doesnt exists there . My file is in **localhost/my_project/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/file.php.** How can I appears this file into the same window as user login after clicking on hypertext ?

I try wp_redirect,header in href attribute but  it is still redirect to wp-admin .

my code

```
<a class="hyper" href="<?php wp_redirect( home_url()."/wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/file.php"); ?>">Register new account</a>
```

Value of siteurl in wp_database is   **http protocol://localhost/my_project/**

Thanks for answer

**EDIT:** I found that I dont need use plugin_url beccause its redirect to plugin url. I need load only page(file.php) into the same page. Its something which is related  with slug_name (I mean $prefix_hook)

Answer (score 0):

so the path is `../wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/file.php`.

```
 <a class="hyper" href="../wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/file.php">Register new account</a>
```

Comment: I wouldn;t recommend that especially if you want your plugin to be WPMU friendly...that way your urls won't work on wpmu where the dashboard address in the network admin is one level higher '/wp-admin/network/...'

Comment: <a class="hyper" href="<?php plugins_url("my_plugin/file.php"); ?>" target="_blank">Register new account</a>  it is absolute URI to this file.php but it was opened the same file with same content. I tried attribute target  only for testing

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `plugins_url( 'file.php' , __FILE__ )` you can read more about the function [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url)

**Edit:**Also you should probably check [Determining Plugin and Content Directories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Determining_Plugin_and_Content_Directories)

Answer (score 0):

do not use wp_redirect for links, it is intended to be a action within php code. If any output has started before the wp_redirect it will fail.  And you need the exit() command afterwards. If you need a url that is a variable, use a function to set it.